# Result set not permitted in BATCH STATEMENT - SQL Anywhere

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am new for SQL ANYWHERE. I am passing Table Name as a input parameter. I want to run both delete and select statement .I don't know where I missed my logic. Could you please help me to do this.

My procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "dba"."spCallTrigger"(
  /* @parameter_name parameter_type [= default_value] [OUTPUT], ... */
                                       @TableName varchar(25) )
AS
BEGIN
    /* Type the procedure statements here */

//Exec "dba"."spCallTrigger" 'GTempTable'

SET OPTION ISQL_PRINT_RESULT_SET='ALL';

DECLARE @sql LONG VARCHAR
SET @sql = 'delete from dba.' + @TableName + ' where 1=2'
Execute ( @sql )

DECLARE @command LONG VARCHAR
SET @command = 'select * from dba.' + @TableName + 'Audit'
Execute ( @command )

END
```

Comment: SQL Anywhere is different from SAP/Sybase ASE. Please clarify which one is it.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE WITH RESULT SET ON  @command
```

This might work.